# replace whole div parent by div child

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have simple html code and I want to replace whole div parent by clicked div child to other div

```
<body>
<div id="parent1">
    <div class="btn" onclick="show('source_div_parent','destination_div_parent')>
    </div>

    <div class="btn" onclick="show('source_div_parent','destination_div_parent')>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="parent2" style="display:none">
    <div class="btn" onclick="show('source_div_parent','destination_div_parent')>
    </div>

    <div class="btn" onclick="show('source_div_parent','destination_div_parent')>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="parent3" style="display:none">
    <div class="btn" onclick="show('source_div_parent','destination_div_parent')>
    </div>

    <div class="btn" onclick="show('source_div_parent','destination_div_parent')>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this my javascript, that i can make and its not that i want

```
function show(par, param_div_id) {
    document.getElementById(par).innerHTML = document.getElementById(param_div_id).innerHTML;
}
```

note: when page first time loads it is only show parent1, after i do click the destination page will show and replace the previous div.

Comment: There is no such element with `id=source_div_parent` in your html which you are using inside `show()`

Comment: it only my example,

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to accomplish.  Do you want to move the clicked child div to a new parent div?

Comment: @codemaker when div class btn clicked, i want to replace whole parent1 to destination div that i've set on function, i dnt know how to make the function,, the only last function i've made like above and it not what i want

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the BEFORE and AFTER version of the HTML that you would like (i.e. - after the click event)?  Also, please give a real sample call to the function, with real document ids.

Comment: i think my answer to you before is clear to explain you for the sample, is my question really not clear for you?, **when div class btn clicked, i want to replace whole parent1 to parent2 based on my way to call function, could you tell me what is the function should be made?**, about the function, forget about my function could you help me to give me what is your way to do that my ask

Comment: Well, (and I don't think I'm alone here), not as clear as it could be. [parent2] and [parent3] are not visible (display: none), therefore, even a function that does what you seem to want, would not necessarily be visible after execution.